# Unable to use a method on a object of the same class

Tags: java, object

I'm implementing a `JFrame`class the has to view a table and do something with it. The table has an `AbstractTableModel` and I've defined a method on it that I want to use in the `JFrame` class. But I'm not able to do this.
here the code:

JFrame class that has to view the JTable

```
public class CreaOrario extends JFrame {


public CreaOrario(int num) {
    initialize(num);
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize(final int semestre) {
    this.setSize(1150,650);
    this.setTitle("Creazione dell'Orario");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    TabellaOrario orarioEditabile = new TabellaOrario(semestre);
    this.getContentPane().add(orarioEditabile, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    final JTable table = orarioEditabile.getTable();
    //now I'd like to do: table.getLesson;
}
}
```

JPanel class that has to be added in JFrame and that contains the table:

```
public class TabellaOrario extends JPanel
{
private JTable table;

public TabellaOrario (int semestre)
{

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
    table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);     
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(510, 350));
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(jps);
    add(new JScrollPane(table));
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setRowHeight(40);

}

public JTable getTable() {
    return table;
}
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{   


private String[] columns = {"","Lunedì","Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato"};


private Object [][] data = {{"8:30 - 9:30","","","","","",""},
        {"9:30 - 10:30","","","","","",""},
        {"10:30 - 11:30","","","","","",""},
        {"11:30 - 12:30","","","","","",""},
        {"12:30 - 13:30","","","","","",""},
        {"13:30 - 14:30","","","","","",""},
        {"14:30 - 15:30","","","","","",""},
        {"15:30 - 16:30","","","","","",""},
        {"16:30 - 17:30","","","","","",""}};



        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columns[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];

        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
            data[row][col] = aValue;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

            }

     }
        public String[] getLesson (int row, int column)
        {
            String value = (String) table.getValueAt(row, column);
            int start = value.indexOf("<b>");
            int end = value.indexOf("</b>");
            String insegnamento = value.substring(start + "<b>".length(), end);

            start = value.lastIndexOf("<b>");
            end = value.lastIndexOf("</b>");
            String aula = value.substring(start + "<b>".length(), end);

            return new String[] {insegnamento,aula};

        }
}
}
```

In the `MyTableModel` class, I've defined the method `getLesson()` that I would like to use in the `CreaOrario` class.

But if in `MyTableModel`I write `table.getLesson()`, it is shown a Message Error that says`The method getLesson() is undefined for the type JTable`.
Why? `table` infact is an `TabellaOrario` object and has `MyTableModel` as model. `getLesson()` is defined for `MyTableModel`, so I would expect that `table.getLesson()` works.

Comment: Can you show relevant code only?

Comment: Yes, just a moment please

Comment: You declare it as a JTable, though; it's just a JTable at that point.

Comment: and in which way I would declare it? If you look to my code, `TabellaOrario` is a JPanel. That because I need to add such a Panel to the JFrame class. I've also implemented a `getTable()` method to get the table in the Panel.  On **this** table I would like to apply the method getLesson. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `table` is declared as `JTable` also `getTable()` returns a `JTable`. You just need a type cast because `getLesson()` does not exist in `JTable`.

You need to call getLesson() like this:

```
String[] lessons = ((TabellaOrario.MyTableModel)table.getModel()).getLesson();
```

Comment: I know, but I can't resolve. Can you write me a snippet? Maybe I will understand seeing the code. By the way, thank you

Comment: thank you.. but the compiler returns `MyTableModel cannot be resolved to a type`.. so it doesn't work...

Comment: Now it works! Can you explain me why it is working now? I don't want to do the same error again

Comment: getLesson() does not exist in JTable class. Your TableOrario class has internal class MyTableModel which has getLesson(). you have TableOrario object but as a JTable. To get the model you need to call table.getModel() but this will not return MyTableModel so we had to cast it to be able to call getLesson() :)

Answer (score 0):

as it seems from your code `getLesson` is defined in `TabellaOrario` and not in `MyTableModel`. that might be the problem....

try to keep the code formation and you'll see that the method isn't implemented inside the class

```
public class TabellaOrario extends JPanel
{
   private JTable table;
   MyTableModel tm;

   public TabellaOrario (int semestre)
   {

       setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
       tm = new MyTableModel();
       table = new JTable(tm);
       // YOU CAN NOW CALL tm.getLesson() OR table.((MyTableModel)getTableModel()).getLesson();
       table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);     
       table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(510, 350));
       JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(table);
       add(jps);
       add(new JScrollPane(table));
       table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
       table.setRowHeight(40);
   }

   public JTable getTable() {
       return table;
   }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
    {   


       private String[] columns = {"","Lunedì","Martedì", "Mercoledì", "Giovedì", "Venerdì", "Sabato"};


       private Object [][] data = {{"8:30 - 9:30","","","","","",""},
            {"9:30 - 10:30","","","","","",""},
            {"10:30 - 11:30","","","","","",""},
            {"11:30 - 12:30","","","","","",""},
            {"12:30 - 13:30","","","","","",""},
            {"13:30 - 14:30","","","","","",""},
            {"14:30 - 15:30","","","","","",""},
            {"15:30 - 16:30","","","","","",""},
            {"16:30 - 17:30","","","","","",""}};



            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columns.length;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int col) {
                return columns[col];
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return data[row][col];

            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
                data[row][col] = aValue;
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);

                }

            public String[] getLesson (int row, int column)
            {
                String value = (String) table.getValueAt(row, column);
                int start = value.indexOf("<b>");
                int end = value.indexOf("</b>");
                String insegnamento = value.substring(start + "<b>".length(), end);

                start = value.lastIndexOf("<b>");
                end = value.lastIndexOf("</b>");
                String aula = value.substring(start + "<b>".length(), end);

                return new String[] {insegnamento,aula};

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, you are right. But, without modify the class (the concept is the same) how would you resolve? thank you

Comment: @Bernheart i've put the full code with proper formation. amazingly i said it 15 minutes ago and nobody noticed....

Comment: I've tried what have you written. the compiler return an error:
`The method getLesson(int, int) is undefined for the type JTable`. the problem is: the `table` is only JTable object? why? I have added a Model to this Jtable and I would expect that the method in `MyTableModel` could be used on the object table

Comment: @Bernheart now i see the problem... `table` is defined as `JTable` with a `TableModel`. to call the `TableModel` methods you need to do is to save the `TableModel` in a parameter and use it. i donno other ways though there are probably some....

Comment: @Bernheart look at my edit, specific in the TabellaOrario cinstructor